# Hide Rows / Autofilter Listener - OpenOffice Basic

Tags: listener, handler, basic

I need to dev Listener to detect changes of isVisible setting for a rows in calc.

Even better it would be for me to have autofilter changes listener - this is also beyond my skills. I would be appreciative for any or both solutions help.

`XEventListener` nor `XModifyListener` dont detects this changes.
Maybe try to use `XChangesListener` `XChangesNotifier`? <- anyway, i had problem to implement it for tests too

```
Sub add_eventsListener
    Dim ePrefix As String, eService As String

    ePrefix = "event_"
    eService = "com.sun.star.document.XEventListener"

    If IsNull(mEventHandler) Then
        mEventHandler = CreateUnoListener(ePrefix, eService)
        ThisComponent.addEventListener(mEventHandler)
    EndIf
End Sub

Sub event_notifyEvent(oEvent)
    msgbox "event: " & oEvent.EventName 
End Sub


Sub add_modifyListener(ByRef Sheet)
    Dim ePrefix As String : Dim eService As String
    Dim cell as Object

    ePrefix = "event_"
    eService = "com.sun.star.util.XModifyListener"

    cell = Sheet.getCellrangeByName("A2:A9") 

    If IsNull(mModifyHandler) Then
        mModifyHandler = CreateUnoListener(ePrefix, eService)
        cell.AddModifyListener(mModifyHandler)
    EndIf
End Sub

Sub event_modified(oEvent)
    'If oEvent.Source.CellAddress.Column <> 0 Then Exit Sub
    Msgbox "changes made"
End Sub
```

where `mEventHandler` and `mModifyHandler` are global

```
Sub add_autofilter(ByRef Sheet)
On Error GoTo Err
    Dim Range As New com.sun.star.table.CellRangeAddress
    Dim FilterOn As Boolean, dRange As Object, cell As Object, row%
    FilterOn = False

    cell = Sheet.getCellRangeByName("A1")
    row = getLastRow(Sheet)

On Error Resume Next
    dRange = ThisComponent.DatabaseRanges.getByName("Symbols")
    FilterOn = dRange.AutoFilter
On Error GoTo 0 : On Error GoTo Err

    If FilterOn Then Exit Sub

    With Range
        .Sheet = 0
        .StartColumn = 0
        .StartRow = 0
        .EndColumn = 0
        .EndRow = row
    End With

    'Range = Sheet.getCellRangeByPosition(0, 0, 0, row)
    ThisComponent.DatabaseRanges.addNewByName("Symbols", Range)
    ThisComponent.DatabaseRanges.getByName("Symbols").AutoFilter = True
Exit Sub
Err:
End Sub


Function getLastRow(ByRef Sheet) As Integer
    Dim cursor
    cursor = Sheet.createCursor()
    cursor.gotoEndOfUsedArea(false)
    getLastRow = cursor.getRangeAddress().EndRow
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

While I am waiting for rational solution, I found a workaround - If no autofilter listener will be possible, Ill have to stay with that:

<strike>add formula in some cell:</strike> (old solution, check EDIT below)

> "=IF(NOW()>0;ROWS_FILTERED();0)"

```
Function ROWS_FILTERED() As Integer 
    If Freezed Then Exit Function
    Dim i%, rows%, Sheet As Object : Sheet = ThisComponent.Sheets(0) 
    rows = getLastRow(Sheet)
    For i = 1 to getLastRow(Sheet)   'row 0 is for labels
        If Sheet.Rows(i).IsVisible = True Then
            rows = rows - 1
        End If
    Next i
    ROWS_FILTERED = rows
End Function
```

And if you make changes where computations are not expected, just assign `True` to `Global Freezed` for that time

---

EDIT:
eureka! I have found this shiny formula that works and updating without workaround:

Eureka! Mimo że nie osiągnąłem rezultatu z czystego BASIC'a, znalazłem genialną formułę, która się odnosi bezpośrednio do autofiltra!! i updateuje bez obejścia:

> "=SUBTOTAL(3;A2:A" & getLastRow(Sheet) + 1 & ")"

*dont forget to include* `getLastRow(ByRef Sheet)` *function to your code*